# Prove that $EF\perp BG$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be acute, $E,F,G$ are 3 points outside it such that $\triangle EAB$ and $\triangle BCF$ are isoscels with $$\angle AEB= \angle BFC=120^{\circ}$$
> And $\triangle AGC$ is equilateral. Prove that $GB\perp EF$.

[image]

The above diagram is not totally accurate but it’s good enough. I’m searching for a cyclic quadrilateral that could help solving the problem, and I think that it should be $BPRF$, but I don’t know how to prove it.

Comment: Use complex numbers

Comment: @Essaidi I’m pretty sure there is an alternative method that just uses angle chasing.

Comment: yes of course. It's just an algebraic solution for a geometric problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a, b, c, d, e, f, g$ the affixes of $A, B, C, E, F, G$ and :
$$j = e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{3}} = -\dfrac{1}{2} + i \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Notice that : $j^3 = 1$ and $1 + j + j^2 = 0$

1. The triangle $AGC$ is equilateral then :
   $$\dfrac{g - a}{c - a} = e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}} = e^{-i\pi} e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}} = -j^2$$
   then $g - a = -j^2 c + j^2 a$ so $g = (1 + j^2)a - j^2 c = -j a - j^2 c$.
2. The triangle $BCF$ is isoscel with angle $\dfrac{2 \pi}{3}$ then :
   $$\dfrac{f - b}{f - c} = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}} = j^2$$
   then $f - b = j f - j c$. We deduce that :
   $$f = \dfrac{b - j c}{1 - j}$$
3. The triangle $EAB$ is isoscel with angle $\dfrac{2 \pi}{3}$ then :
   $$\dfrac{e - a}{e - b} = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}} = j^2$$
   then $e - a = j e - j b$. We deduce that :
   $$e = \dfrac{a - j b}{1 - j}$$

We conclude that :
$$g - b = -j^2 c - j a - b$$
and :
$$e - f = \dfrac{a - j b}{1 - j} - \dfrac{b - j c}{1 - j} = \dfrac{a - (1 + j) b + j c}{1 - j} = \dfrac{a + j^2 b + j c}{1 - j} = \dfrac{j a + b + j^2 c}{j(1 - j)}$$
then :
$$\dfrac{g - b}{e - f} = -j(1 - j) = -j + j^2 = -j - 1 - j = -2j - 1 = 1 - i \sqrt{3} - 1 = - i \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{R}$$
Finally $GB \perp EF$.

Comment: We also have : $$BG = EF \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, recall Napoleon's theorem. If we construct equilateral triangles $AGC$, $CHB$, and $BIA$ on the outside of triangle $ABC$, then $BG, AH, CI$

- Have the same length.
- Are concurrent at $K$, the Fermat point of triangle $ABC$,
- Each meet at $60 ^ \circ$

Now, observe that triangle $BEF$, rotated about $B$ by $30^\circ$ and expanded by $ \sqrt{3}$ gives us triangle $BAH$. Hence, $ AH = \sqrt{3} EF$ and is obtained by a rotation of $30^\circ$.
From above, $BG$ is a rotation of $AH$ by $60^\circ$, hence $EF \perp BG$ (and $\sqrt{3} EF = BG$).